# Is $f:\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$, $f(m,n)=31m+23n$ injective?

Tags: functions

Is $f:\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb Z$, $f(m,n)=31m+23n$ injective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Can you find $(m,n)$ such that $31m + 23n = 0$?

2) What happens if you multiply $31m + 23n = 0$ by some integer? Can you spot more solutions?

Comment: @user50554: You have at least, $(23,-31)$ in the $\ker f$, so it is not injective.

Answer (score 4):

$f(23,0)=f(0,31)$ thus $f$ is not injective.